# Merge multiple sonarqube project and get aggregate result

Tags: sonarqube

I have multiple sonar project scans and all are of .net language.

I want to merge result of this projects in single project, to get overall counts.

[image]

My requirement is to get combined data for all 3 projects.
i.e.

```
LOC = 88393, 
Bugs = 585 (527+28+30), 
code smells = 1934
```

I tried to get this detail with api and combine it, but didn't found api to get project details.

API Reference I take: https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392165

Sonar version: 5.6.5

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your version of SonarQube (found in the footer of every page).

Comment: Thanks, I have added version detail.

Comment: Hi, I think this is what are you looking for-
 timemachine with combined metrics, https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392163
otherwise maybe simply from metrics https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392172

Comment: I have tried matrix api, /api/metrics/ncloc  
>> curl.exe -u <mykey>: https://<serverurl>/api/metrics/ncloc -k and   >> curl.exe -u <mykey>: https://<serverurl>/api/metrics -k  
In response I am getting "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." How can i pass project Id in matrix api? Do i need to create any matrix manually?   I am getting all projects list with "/api/projects" >> curl.exe -u <mykey>: https://<serverurl>/api/projects -k

Answer (score 0):

If you can't make the web services work for you, then you'll have to fall back to a [commercial feature](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/), Applications, but you're going to have to upgrade to at least the latest LTS (currrently 6.7.2) to get it.